# When submitting the form site.com/blog/wp-admin it goes to site.com/wp-admin

Tags: admin, wp-admin

I have 2 wordpress websites. One at `site.com` and the other at `site.com/blog`.

I want to go to administration of `site.com/blog`, but when I point to `site.com/blog/wp-login.php` or `site.com/blog/wp-admin/` and login, it goes to `site.com/wp-login`!!!! (Both wordpresses have the same user/passwords)

Please help me stay at when I point the browser to!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define the home url, in the installation folder of `site.com/blog`:

```
define( 'WP_HOME',' http://site.com/blog' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://site.com/blog' );
```

I think this can solve your problem.

Comment: In the wp-config.php

Comment: Sorry, I was very new to wordpress, I got that it was a very simple question! Thank you :)